# Browser based IDE with code navigation

Tags: javascript, ide, editor

Do you know of any IDE, text editor, code editor, whathaveyou, where I can see an example of how to write code navigation functions?

A code navigation function could be for example, providing a visual list of methods or a document tree of the current file so that I can click on an entry to jump to that place in the file.

Note: obviously answers need to be about open source projects so that one can read the code.

Comment: i was like, really, a whole page already?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Javascript_IDE

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to take a look at [Codiac project](https://github.com/Codiad/Codiad).

> Codiad is a web-based IDE framework with a small footprint and minimal requirements. The system is still early in development, and while it has been proven extremely stable please be sure have a backup system if you use it in any production work.

It has nice graphics and it is still in developement.

[**Here you can test it.**](http://demo.codiad.com/)

---

Another popular IDE is [Cloud9](https://c9.io/).

> Cloud9 IDE is an online development environment for Javascript and Node.js applications as well as HTML, CSS, PHP, Java, Ruby and 23 other languages.

[Here is its Github repo.](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/)

Comment: curious: what does the support for 23 other languages entail? are we talking syntax highlighting only, or does it offer the kind of code management tools OP mentions? i mean, if there;s no tools, why stop at 23...